# How to get order id or any reference id on successful payment authorize.net SIM Method

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am integrating Authorize.net Payment gateway (SIM Method) to my website. I have actually integrated it. But I am facing some problem in verifying the successful payment in relay response. As in most of the payment we pass an orderid or a reference number which in turn we can use to verify the particular order is complete. But how we can implement this on Authorized.net SIM method? I am using relay response to get the details of transaction.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What isn't working? What have you tried? We can't help you without knowing what's actually wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Authorize.net SIM API that you are referring to is deprecated and is replaced by the Accept Hosted method.

Using ths SIM API, the Payment Gateway Response contains the x_response_code, the value of which indicates the overall status of the transaction.

- 1 - Approved
- 2 - Declined
- 3 - Error
- 4 - Held for Review

There are also the following SIM API Payment Gateway fields returned in the response:

- x_trans_id: The payment-gateway-assigned
  identification number for the transaction
- x_invoice_num:
  The merchant-assigned invoice number for the transaction. Format:
  20-character maximum (no symbols)
- x_po_num: The merchant-assigned purchase order number. Format: 25-character maximum (no symbols)